# Overloading == operator in unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, unordered-set

I'm trying to create an `unordered_set` of `Intervals` as defined below:

```
struct Interval {
  unsigned int b;  //begining index
  unsigned int e;  //end index
  bool updated;   //true if concat.  initially false
  int patternIndex;  //pattern index. valid for single pattern
  int proteinIndex;   //protein index.  for retrieving the pattern
};

struct Hash {
  size_t operator()(const Interval &interval) const;
};

struct IntervalEquality {
  bool operator == (Interval const &lhs, Interval const &rhs);
};


bool IntervalEquality::operator == (Interval const &lhs, Interval const &rhs){
  return ((lhs.b == rhs.b) && (lhs.e == rhs.e) && (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex));
}

size_t Hash::operator()(const Interval &interval) const{
  string temp = to_string(interval.b) + to_string(interval.e) + to_string(interval.proteinIndex);
  return hash<string>()(temp);
}

unordered_set<Interval, Hash> test;
```

Here, I am declaring the `==` operator in my header file and defining it in my .cpp file (as I am successfully doing for other operators). When I compile the above code, I get errors about the `==` operator requiring exactly one argument.  E.g., `'bool IntervalEquality::operator==(const Interval&, const Interval&)' must take exactly one argument`

If I try to take an alternate route and declare *and* define `==` in my header file like so:

```
bool operator == (Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs){
    return (lhs.b == rhs.b) && 
           (lhs.e == rhs.e) && 
           (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex); 
}
```

I get errors about multiple definitions of `==`

Does anyone have an idea of how I can resolve this?  Help much appreciated!

Comment: The implementation of `==` should be `return ((lhs.b == rhs.b) && (lhs.e == rhs.e /*<<<= e, not b */) && (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the header:

```
bool operator== (Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs);
```

Put this in the .cpp file:

```
bool operator== (Interval const& lhs, Interval const& rhs)
{
  return (lhs.b == rhs.b) && 
         (lhs.e == rhs.e) && 
         (lhs.proteinIndex == rhs.proteinIndex); 
}
```

While you can create an equality lambda, in this case this equality makes sense for a general equality.

The only thing I'd be careful of is the fact that your `==` isn't full equality.  If one `Interval` differs only by `updated` or `patternIndex` from another and have a hash collision, they will silently overwrite the other.

Comment: You could also add the keyword `inline` before the `operator==` in the header and leave the function implementation there, but first find out what `inline` keyword does (it has little to do with "inlineing" methods or functions).

Comment: @user2052561 FYI there is basically no time it's legit to provide an operator== for an object without providing !=, and usually you also want <, <=, >, >= too. If it's clear what object == otherObject would do go ahead and provide this, otherwise do just provide the unordered_set a comparer as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `IntervalEquality::operator==` to `operator()`. Then define your `unordered_set` like so:

```
unordered_set<Interval, Hash, IntervalEquality> test;
```

The problem is that you defined what should be a namespace scope `operator==` as a member function. Namespace scope equality operators take 2 arguments and compare them. Member function equality operators take 1 argument and compare it to the class which is belongs to.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm wondering, in this case, how does the compiler know to use my equality operator (I went with the `operator ()` option) for my `unordered_set`?  Should I not declare it like so:  `unordered_set<Interval, Hash, IntervalEquality> test`?